# what is the absolute path of a folder in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I want to run an already existing app on docker. The app interacts with some files on a folder. So i am trying to hook up a volume.

Here is the docker-compose:

```
test:
    container_name: test
    volumes: 
      - C:\test\:\test\

    build: .
```

When i hook into the docker image i can see that the folder is created on the root folder. Now i need to write the correct path to that folder into the application settings.

Before it was something like this:

```
"test": {
  "Path": "C:\\test\\"
}
```

But i dont know how to get the absolute path of my folder from inside docker, so my app can understand where to search for it.

Thank you

EDIT: it looks like the problem was on my side: the way i defined the volumes created a folder with the name "\test\" ... doing C:\test:/test/ instead did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you’re building your own Docker image, you control the filesystem layout entirely.  For Linux-based images it’s common to follow the FHS standard (I think the standard MySQL image stores its data in `/var/lib/mysql`) but it’s also common enough to just store data in subdirectories of the root directory (`/data` or `/config` or what not).

If you have a setup like this, your image should pick a path.  If the only thing in the configuration is the location of that directory, it’s fine to hard-code it in the image.  However you document your image (even if it’s just a standard `docker-compose.yml` file) mention that you have this fixed path; it doesn’t need to match the host path (if any) on any particular system.